# Get JWT by sending HTML form in POST request to private API

Tags: javascript, html, json, post

I have created a very simple html page with 2 inputs and a button (username, password and log in/submit). When I press submit, the username and password is converted into JSON, and sent as the body of a POST request to a private API which I have no control over. The API should then respond with another JSON containing a JWT access token. I then need to put this token into the request header of a GET request (Bearer token), but I haven't gotten this far yet, hence why I'm here.

I have tested the API with Postman, and it is working perfectly as expected. I am now trying to do what Postman does, only in my own small web application.

The JSON I need to send is like this:

```
{"username": "someUsername", "password": "somePassword"}
```

And the response is like this:

```
{"access_token": "A very long random string"}
```

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="apirequest.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Send POST request</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus /> 
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="getToken()">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

apirequest.js this URL is not the real one

```
alert("script loaded");
var token_;

function getToken() {

    alert("button pressed");

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var key;
    var username_ = document.getElementById("username").val();
    var password_ = document.getElementById("password").val();

    request.open("POST", "https://api.dummyurl.test", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(JSON.stringify({
        username: username_,
        password: password_
    }));
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var response = request.responseText;
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            key = obj.access_token; // store the value of the accesstoken
            token_ = key; // store token in global variable "token_"
            alert(token_); //test if token is stored
        }
    }
}
```

I have put some alerts in there just to test things; I get "script loaded" and "button pressed", but not the alert with the token.

I have also tried with AJAX/jQuery to no avail, also no alert pop up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".btn").click(function() {
                alert("Script loaded");
                const Data = {
                    "username" : document.getElementById("username").val(),
                    "password" : document.getElementById("password").val()
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url : "https://api.dummyurl.test",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : Data,
                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(result) {
                        alert(result)
                        console.log(result)
                    },
                    error : function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

I load the page and get "script loaded", then I enter a valid username and password, then I get "button pressed". The page just refreshes and I get "script loaded" again with the last username already typed in. None of the questions I've read have had an answer that works for me. Do you see any problems with my code? Also, as a last note; I'd like to use the first script example as that one is much easier to understand and work with for me.

### Update

So, it's kind of working. I didn't know Postman generated code I could copy. As mentioned, I have tested the API with Postman and it works. Here's what the script looks like now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var settings = {
            "async" : true,
            "crossDomain" : true,
            "url" : "https://api.dummyurl.test",
            "method" : "POST",
            "headers" : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "cache-control" : "no-cache"
                    },
                    "processData" : false,
                    "data" : "{  \r\n\"Username\":\"someUsername\",\r\n\"Password\":\"somePassword\"\r\n}"
                    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        });
    })
```

I actually got the access token from this. The problem now is that username and password is hardcoded (not from html input) and that the script runs as soon as the page is loaded. Any ideas how I can make the script run only after I press the button? And how I can replace the hardcoded username and password with the values from the input fields? Postman generated code with so many \ and ", can I still use variables and not strings inside that line of code?

I just tried reformatting the data to `{"Username":"someUsername","Password":"somePassword"}` and it wouldn't work that way, so I guess the \r\n is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot the method on your form element, While serialize method will get form values, try to set your form like this:

```
   <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Send POST request</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus /> 
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="return getToken(this.form)">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>


   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        function getToken(form){
          var formData = $(form).serialize();
          $.post("https://api.dummyurl.test", formData).done(function(result){
            alert(result);
            console.log(result)
          })
          return true;
        }

      })
   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried implementing your solution but then I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined" on the line "var formData = $(form).serialize();".. Also, sorry if this sounds stupid, but I see you still use getToken() in the onclick, but you're using the jquery script in your answer, not my vanilla getToken function from apirequest.js. Should I use both or...?

Comment: Create the function getToken after document.ready with argument form.

Comment: So I did that like this: $(document).ready(function getToken(form) and ran it, then I got Uncaught ReferenceError: getToken is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick... So then I tried removing the onclick on the button since we already have $(".btn").click(function(), then I got no errors and the pop up "Script loaded", but nothing else happened. Its like the success and error functions are not running, nothing gets logged.

Comment: Remove the  $(".btn").click(function() {}, it doesn't need anymore already have the onclick handler.

Comment: Ayy, now we're seeing progress. The error function fired now (as soon as I loaded the page), most likely because the script is sending the post request as soon as the page is loaded, and not waiting until I press the button. If you want, here is the console error message https://imgur.com/0YYNXvQ

Comment: I've done some research on the serialize function because it was new to me. It seems it turns the form values into a valid querystring, and not a JSON object. I'm 99% sure the API only accepts a post request with the body being a JSON object formatted like this: {"username": "someUsername", "password": "somePassword"}. Your updated ajax code does not recieve a response from the API. I'm sorry if it seems like I'm putting all the work on you, but I'm really stuck without help getting through this first step...

Comment: Convert form value to a JSON: var formData = JSON.stringify($(form).serialize())

Comment: I'm sorry, nothing is happening. After putting some alerts to test where things go wrong, it seems like getToken(form) never executes. I feel like getToken runs as soon as the page is loaded, and not waiting until the button is pressed.  So the post request is rejected by the API before I even send the right form. But if thats the case, the alert i put inside getToken should show, which it doesnt. I really don't know anymore. Does it have something to do with https instead of http? Is the form value correctly formatted? My head is about to explode lol.

Comment: Just as I was about to give up for the night, I actually made 2 steps forward and only 1 step back. See the update at the bottom of the original post.